# What are the possible consequences of using unsafe conversion from []byte to string in go?

Tags: string, pointers, go, unsafe

The preferred way of converting `[]byte` to `string` is this:

```
var b []byte
// fill b
s := string(b)
```

In this code byte slice is copied, which can be a problem in situations where performance is important.

When performance is critical, one can consider performing the unsafe conversion:

```
var b []byte
// fill b
s :=  *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
```

My question is: what can go wrong when using the unsafe conversion? I known that `string` should be immutable and if we change `b`, `s` will also be changed. And still: so what? Is it all bad that can happen?

Comment: Never use unsafe. Performance is never that critical.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying something that the language spec guarantees to be immutable is an act of treason.

Since the spec guarantees that `string`s are immutable, compilers are allowed to generate code that caches their values and does other optimization based on this. You can't change values of `string`s in any normal way, and if you resort to dirty ways (like package `unsafe`) to still do it, you lose all the guarantees provided by the spec, and by continuing to use the modified `string`s, you may bump into "bugs" and unexpected things randomly.

For example if you use a `string` as a key in a map and you change the `string` after you put it into the map, you might not be able to find the associated value in the map using either the original or the modified value of the `string` (this is implementation dependent).

To demonstrate this, see this example:

```
m := map[string]int{}
b := []byte("hi")
s := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
m[s] = 999

fmt.Println("Before:", m)

b[0] = 'b'
fmt.Println("After:", m)

fmt.Println("But it's there:", m[s], m["bi"])

for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    m[strconv.Itoa(i)] = i
}
fmt.Println("Now it's GONE:", m[s], m["bi"])
for k, v := range m {
    if k == "bi" {
        fmt.Println("But still there, just in a different bucket: ", k, v)
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/VbQ90I5Fnd)):

```
Before: map[hi:999]
After: map[bi:<nil>]
But it's there: 999 999
Now it's GONE: 0 0
But still there, just in a different bucket:  bi 999
```

At first, we just see some weird result: simple `Println()` is not able to find its value. It sees something (key is found), but value is displayed as `nil` which is not even a valid value for the value type `int` (zero value for `int` is `0`).

If we grow the map to be big (we add 1000 elements), internal data structure of the map gets restructured. After this, we're not even able to find our value by explicitly asking for it with the appropriate key. It is still in the map as iterating over all its key-value pairs we find it, but since hash code changes as the value of the `string` changes, most likely it is searched for in a different bucket than where it is (or where it should be).

Also note that code using package `unsafe` may work as you expect it now, but the same code might work completely differently (meaning it may break) with a future (or old) version of Go as *"packages that import unsafe may be non-portable and are not protected by the Go 1 compatibility guidelines"*.

Also you may run into unexpected errors as the modified `string` might be used in different ways. Someone might just copy the string header, someone may copy its content. See this example:

```
b := []byte{'h', 'i'}
s := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))

s2 := s                 // Copy string header
s3 := string([]byte(s)) // New string header but same content
fmt.Println(s, s2, s3)
b[0] = 'b'

fmt.Println(s == s2)
fmt.Println(s == s3)
```

We created 2 new local variables `s2` and `s3` using `s`, `s2` initialized by copying the string header of `s`, and `s3` is initialized with a new `string` value (new string header) but with the same content. Now if you modify the original `s`, you would expect in a correct program that comparing the new strings to the original you would get the same result be it either `true` or `false` (based on if values were cached, but should be the same).

But the output is (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xHgLh3gW64)):

```
hi hi hi
true
false
```