# How to use unsafe get a byte slice from a string without memory copy

Tags: string, performance, go, slice

I have read about "https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25484" about no-copy conversion from `[]byte` to `string`.

I am wondering if there is a way to convert a string to a byte slice without memory copy?

I am writing a program which processes terra-bytes data, if every string is copied twice in memory, it will slow down the progress. And I do not care about mutable/unsafe, only internal usage, I just need the speed as fast as possible.

Example:

```
var s string
// some processing on s, for some reasons, I must use string here
// ...
// then output to a writer
gzipWriter.Write([]byte(s))  // !!! Here I want to avoid the memory copy, no WriteString
```

So the question is: is there a way to prevent from the memory copying? I know maybe I need the unsafe package, but I do not know how. I have searched a while, no answer till now, neither the SO showed related answers works.

---

Update: for Go 1.20, the official solution is:

- https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#String
- https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#StringData

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Getting the content of a `string` as a `[]byte` without copying in general is only possible using [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), because `string`s in Go are immutable, and without a copy it would be possible to modify the contents of the `string` (by changing the elements of the byte slice).

So using `unsafe`, this is how it could look like (corrected, working solution):

```
func unsafeGetBytes(s string) []byte {
    return (*[0x7fff0000]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(
        (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data),
    )[:len(s):len(s)]
}
```

This solution is from [Ian Lance Taylor](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/Zsfk-VMd_fU/m/O1ru4fO-BgAJ).

One thing to note here: the empty string `""` has no bytes as its length is zero. This means there is no guarantee what the `Data` field may be, it may be zero or an arbitrary address shared among the zero-size variables. If an empty string may be passed, that must be checked explicitly (although there's no need to get the bytes of an empty string without copying...):

```
func unsafeGetBytes(s string) []byte {
    if s == "" {
        return nil // or []byte{}
    }
    return (*[0x7fff0000]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(
        (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data),
    )[:len(s):len(s)]
}
```

Original, **wrong** solution was:

```
func unsafeGetBytesWRONG(s string) []byte {
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)) // WRONG!!!!
}
```

See [Nuno Cruces's answer](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/Zsfk-VMd_fU/m/O1ru4fO-BgAJ) below for reasoning.

Testing it:

```
s := "hi"
data := unsafeGetBytes(s)
fmt.Println(data, string(data))

data = unsafeGetBytes("gopher")
fmt.Println(data, string(data))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A2gzHUYJJwr)):

```
[104 105] hi
[103 111 112 104 101 114] gopher
```

**BUT:** You wrote you want this because you need performance. You also mentioned you want to compress the data. Please know that compressing data (using `gzip`) requires a lot more computation than just copying a few bytes! You will not see any noticeable performance gain by using this!

Instead when you want to write `string`s to an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), it's recommended to do it via [`io.WriteString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteString) function which if possible will do so without making a copy of the `string` (by checking and calling `WriteString()` method which if exists is most likely does it better than copying the `string`). For details, see [What's the difference between ResponseWriter.Write and io.WriteString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863374/whats-the-difference-between-responsewriter-write-and-io-writestring/37872799#37872799)

There are also ways to access the contents of a `string` without converting it to `[]byte`, such as indexing, or using a loop where the compiler optimizes away the copy:

```
s := "something"
for i, v := range []byte(s) { // Copying s is optimized away
    // ...
}
```

**Also see related questions:**

[[]byte(string) vs []byte(*string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470284/golang-bytestring-vs-bytestring/43470344#43470344)

[What are the possible consequences of using unsafe conversion from []byte to string in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952378/what-are-the-possible-consequences-of-using-unsafe-conversion-from-byte-to-str/33953027#33953027)

[What is the difference between the string and []byte in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625959/what-is-the-difference-between-the-string-and-byte-in-go/32626057#32626057)

[Does conversion between alias types in Go create copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253768/does-convertion-between-alias-types-in-go-create-copies/32253871#32253871)

[How does type conversion internally work? What is the memory utilization for the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207920/how-does-type-conversion-internally-work-what-is-the-memory-utilization-for-the/45209033#45209033)

Comment: panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:52] with capacity 0

Comment: @RFC7676 Care to share the code that produces that error? The code I've shared works on the Go Playground.

Comment: go version go1.14.1 linux/amd64 https://play.golang.org/p/XwD6lmljSO8

Comment: @RFC7676 There is no guarantee that the returned slice points to valid memory area unless you keep a reference to the string. Since your example does not do so, an aggressive gc is allowed to "erase" the string from memory right after the `unsafeGetBytes()` call. Please see [In Go, when will a variable become unreachable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588639/in-go-when-will-a-variable-become-unreachable/37591282#37591282) One "obvious" solution is to use `runtime.KeepAlive()`. All in all, try to stay away from package `unsafe` as much as possible, use only if there is no other option.

Comment: It explains the matter.

Comment: `func unsafeGetBytes(s string)` By the way，does parameter passing do not cause memory copy?

Comment: @RFC7676 It does, but a `string` value is just a header holding a pointer (and length). The string content is not copied. See [String memory usage in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851788/string-memory-usage-in-golang/52851967#52851967) and [GoLang - memory allocation - \[\]byte vs string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904674/golang-memory-allocation-byte-vs-string/55904901#55904901).

Comment: The conversion is not correct. Calling `data = append(data, '!')` crashes it. It should be: `return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&struct{string; int}{s, len(s)}))`

Comment: And, it needn't to keep a reference to the string to make the result slice valid.

Comment: @T.L You're right. I've fixed a code, showing Ian Lance Taylor's interesting solution.

Comment: It would be more theory perfect to replace `0x7fff0000` with `^uint(0) >> 1`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878590/the-maximum-value-for-an-int-type-in-go

Comment: Sorry, my bad, using ^uint(0) >> 1 will get a "type [9223372036854775807]byte larger than address space" error. So here it is hard to make it perfect with Ian Lance Taylor's solution, at least for the current Go toolchain version, 1.16.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to get rid of the bounds check when slicing the pointer to array (other than by using `gcflags=-B`). Even when truncating `len(s)` to an integer type smaller than `0x7fff0000`, like `int16`. Not sure if this is a mistake on my end or just intentional.

Comment: the `StringHeader.Data` of an empty string is zero, leading to a nil pointer panic for the `0x7fff0000` version. [go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qtBfUdZTUKl)

Comment: @McFog You're right. I updated the answer. Although there's no need to get the bytes of an empty string without copying...

Answer (score 13):

After some extensive investigation, I believe I've discovered the most efficient way of getting a `[]byte` from a `string` as of Go 1.17 (this is for i386/x86_64 `gc`; I haven't tested other architectures.) The trade-off of being efficient code here is being inefficient to code, though.

Before I say anything else, it should be made clear that the differences are ultimately very small and probably inconsequential -- the info below is for fun/educational purposes only.

---

#### Summary

With some minor alterations, the accepted answer illustrating the technique of slicing a pointer to array is the most efficient way. That being said, I wouldn't be surprised if `unsafe.Slice` becomes the (decisively) better choice in the future.

---

#### unsafe.Slice

`unsafe.Slice` currently has the advantage of being slightly more readable, but I'm skeptical about it's performance. It looks like it makes a call to `runtime.unsafeslice`. The following is the gc amd64 1.17 assembly of the function provided in [Atamiri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68195226/7314180) (`FUNCDATA` omitted). Note the stack check (lack of `NOSPLIT`):

```
unsafeGetBytes_pc0:
        TEXT    "".unsafeGetBytes(SB), ABIInternal, $48-16
        CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        JLS     unsafeGetBytes_pc86
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        SUBQ    $48, SP
        MOVQ    BP, 40(SP)
        LEAQ    40(SP), BP

        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        MOVQ    BX, ""..autotmp_4+24(SP)
        MOVQ    AX, "".s+56(SP)
        MOVQ    BX, "".s+64(SP)
        MOVQ    "".s+56(SP), DX
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        MOVQ    DX, ""..autotmp_5+32(SP)
        LEAQ    type.uint8(SB), AX
        MOVQ    BX, CX
        MOVQ    DX, BX
        PCDATA  $1, $1
        CALL    runtime.unsafeslice(SB)
        MOVQ    ""..autotmp_5+32(SP), AX
        MOVQ    ""..autotmp_4+24(SP), BX
        MOVQ    BX, CX
        MOVQ    40(SP), BP
        ADDQ    $48, SP
        RET
unsafeGetBytes_pc86:
        NOP
        PCDATA  $1, $-1
        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        MOVQ    AX, 8(SP)
        MOVQ    BX, 16(SP)
        CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
        MOVQ    8(SP), AX
        MOVQ    16(SP), BX
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        JMP     unsafeGetBytes_pc0
```

Other unimportant fun facts about the above (easily subject to change): compiled size of `3326`B; has an inline cost of `7`; correct escape analysis: `s leaks to ~r1 with derefs=0`.

---

#### Carefully Modifying *reflect.SliceHeader

This method has the advantage/disadvantage of letting one modify the internal state of a slice directly. Unfortunately, due it's multiline nature and use of uintptr, the GC can easily mess things up if one is not careful about keeping a reference to the original string. (Here I avoided creating temporary pointers to reduce inline cost and to avoid needing to add `runtime.KeepAlive`):

```
func unsafeGetBytes(s string) (b []byte) {
    (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)).Data = (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data
    (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)).Cap = len(s)
    (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)).Len = len(s)
    return
}
```

The corresponding assembly on amd64 (`FUNCDATA` omitted):

```
        TEXT    "".unsafeGetBytes(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $32-16
        SUBQ    $32, SP
        MOVQ    BP, 24(SP)
        LEAQ    24(SP), BP

        MOVQ    AX, "".s+40(SP)
        MOVQ    BX, "".s+48(SP)
        MOVQ    $0, "".b(SP)
        MOVUPS  X15, "".b+8(SP)
        MOVQ    "".s+40(SP), DX
        MOVQ    DX, "".b(SP)
        MOVQ    "".s+48(SP), CX
        MOVQ    CX, "".b+16(SP)
        MOVQ    "".s+48(SP), BX
        MOVQ    BX, "".b+8(SP)
        MOVQ    "".b(SP), AX
        MOVQ    24(SP), BP
        ADDQ    $32, SP
        RET
```

Other unimportant fun facts about the above (easily subject to change): compiled size of `3700`B; has an inline cost of `20`; subpar escape analysis: `s leaks to {heap} with derefs=0`.

---

###### Unsafer version of modifying SliceHeader

Adapted from [Nuno Cruces' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66218124/7314180). This relies on the inherent structural similarity between `StringHeader` and `SliceHeader`, so in a sense it breaks "more easily". Additionally, it temporarily creates an illegal state where `cap(b)` (being `0`) is less than `len(b)`.

```
func unsafeGetBytes(s string) (b []byte) {
    *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)) = s
    (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)).Cap = len(s)
    return
}
```

Corresponding assembly (`FUNCDATA` omitted):

```
        TEXT    "".unsafeGetBytes(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $32-16
        SUBQ    $32, SP
        MOVQ    BP, 24(SP)
        LEAQ    24(SP), BP
        MOVQ    AX, "".s+40(FP)

        MOVQ    $0, "".b(SP)
        MOVUPS  X15, "".b+8(SP)
        MOVQ    AX, "".b(SP)
        MOVQ    BX, "".b+8(SP)
        MOVQ    BX, "".b+16(SP)
        MOVQ    "".b(SP), AX
        MOVQ    BX, CX
        MOVQ    24(SP), BP
        ADDQ    $32, SP
        NOP
        RET
```

Other unimportant details: compiled size `3636`B, inline cost of `11`, with subpar escape analysis: `s leaks to {heap} with derefs=0`.

---

#### Slicing a pointer to array

This is the accepted answer (shown here for comparison) -- its primary disadvantage is its ugliness (viz. magic number `0x7fff0000`). There's also the tiniest possibility of getting a string bigger than the array, and an unavoidable bounds check.

```
func unsafeGetBytes(s string) []byte {
    return (*[0x7fff0000]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(
        (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data),
    )[:len(s):len(s)]
}
```

Corresponding assembly (`FUNCDATA` removed).

```
        TEXT    "".unsafeGetBytes(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $24-16
        SUBQ    $24, SP
        MOVQ    BP, 16(SP)
        LEAQ    16(SP), BP

        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        MOVQ    AX, "".s+32(SP)
        MOVQ    BX, "".s+40(SP)
        MOVQ    "".s+32(SP), AX
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        TESTB   AL, (AX)
        NOP
        CMPQ    BX, $2147418112
        JHI     unsafeGetBytes_pc54
        MOVQ    BX, CX
        MOVQ    16(SP), BP
        ADDQ    $24, SP
        RET
unsafeGetBytes_pc54:
        MOVQ    BX, DX
        MOVL    $2147418112, BX
        PCDATA  $1, $1
        NOP
        CALL    runtime.panicSlice3Alen(SB)
        XCHGL   AX, AX
```

Other unimportant details: compiled size `3142`B, inline cost of `9`, with correct escape analysis: `s leaks to ~r1 with derefs=0`

Note the `runtime.panicSlice3Alen` -- this is bounds check that checks that `len(s)` is within `0x7fff0000`.

---

##### Improved slicing pointer to array

This is what I've concluded to be the most efficient method as of Go 1.17. I basically modified the accepted answer to eliminate the bounds check, and found a "more meaningful" constant (`math.MaxInt32`) to use than `0x7fff0000`. Using `MaxInt32` preserves 32-bit compatibility.

```golang
func unsafeGetBytes(s string) []byte {
    const MaxInt32 = 1<<31 - 1
    return (*[MaxInt32]byte)(unsafe.Pointer((*reflect.StringHeader)(
                    unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data))[:len(s)&MaxInt32:len(s)&MaxInt32]
}
```

Corresponding assembly (`FUNCDATA` removed):

```
        TEXT    "".unsafeGetBytes(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $0-16

        PCDATA  $0, $-2
        MOVQ    AX, "".s+8(SP)
        MOVQ    BX, "".s+16(SP)
        MOVQ    "".s+8(SP), AX
        PCDATA  $0, $-1
        TESTB   AL, (AX)
        ANDQ    $2147483647, BX
        MOVQ    BX, CX
        RET
```

Other unimportant details: compiled size `3188`B, inline cost of `13`, and correct escape analysis: `s leaks to ~r1 with derefs=0`

---

Comment: What about `*(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&struct{string; int}{s, len(s)}))`? ISTM that it has inline cost 9, correct escape analysis, no meaningless constants, all in a single expression. It breaks if representation breaks, but that's pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 12):

#### Go 1.20 (February 2023)

You can use [`unsafe.StringData`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe@master#StringData) to greatly simplify [YenForYang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69231355/4108803):

> StringData returns a pointer to the underlying bytes of str. For an empty string the return value is unspecified, and may be nil.
>
> Since Go strings are immutable, the bytes returned by StringData must not be modified.

```
func main() {
    str := "foobar"
    d := unsafe.StringData(str)
    b := unsafe.Slice(d, len(str))
    fmt.Printf("%T, %s\n", b, b) // []uint8, foobar (byte is alias of uint8)
}
```

Go tip playground: https://go.dev/play/p/FIXe0rb8YHE?v=gotip

Remember that you can't assign to `b[n]`. The memory is still read-only.

Answer (score 11):

**In go 1.17, I'd recommend `unsafe.Slice` as more readable:**

```
unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer((*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data)), len(s))
```

I think that this also works (doesn't violate any `unsafe.Pointer` rules), with the benefit that it works for a `const` `s`:

```
*(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&struct{string; int}{s, len(s)}))
```

---

*Commentary bellow is regarding the accepted answer as it originally stood. The accepted answer now mentions an (authoritative) solution from Ian Lance Taylor. Keeping it as it points out a common error.*

---

The accepted answer is wrong, and may produce the panic @RFC mentioned in the comments. The explanation by @icza about GC and keep alive is misguided.

The reason capacity is zero (or even an arbitrary value) is more prosaic.

A slice is:

```
type SliceHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
    Cap  int
}
```

A string is:

```
type StringHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
}
```

Converting a byte slice to a string can be "safely" done as the `strings.Builder` [does it](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder.String):

```
func (b *Builder) String() string {
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b.buf))
}
```

This will copy the `Data` pointer and `Len` from the slice to the string.

The opposite conversion is not "safe" because `Cap` doesn't get set to the correct value.

---

*The following (originally by me) is **also** wrong because it violates `unsafe.Pointer` rule #1.*

---

<s>This is the correct code, that fixes the panic:</s>

```
var buf = *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&str))
(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf)).Cap = len(str)
```

<s>Or perhaps:</s>

```
var buf []byte
*(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf)) = str
(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf)).Cap = len(str)
```

---

I should add that all these conversions **are unsafe** in the sense that strings are expected to be immutable, and byte arrays/slices mutable.

But if you know for sure that the byte slice won't be mutated, you won't get bounds (or GC) issues with the above conversions.

Answer (score 4):

In Go 1.17, one can now use `unsafe.Slice`, so the accepted answer can be rewritten as follows:

```
func unsafeGetBytes(s string) []byte {
        return unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer((*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data)), len(s))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the goal by this:

```
func TestString(t *testing.T) {

    b := []byte{'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3', '4'}
    s := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    sb := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))

    addr1 := unsafe.Pointer(&b)
    addr2 := unsafe.Pointer(&s)
    addr3 := unsafe.Pointer(&sb)

    fmt.Print("&b=", addr1, "\n&s=", addr2, "\n&sb=", addr3, "\n")

    hdr1 := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    hdr2 := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    hdr3 := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&sb))

    fmt.Print("b.data=", hdr1.Data, "\ns.data=", hdr2.Data, "\nsb.data=", hdr3.Data, "\n")

    b[0] = 'X'
    sb[1] = 'Y'  // if sb is from a string directly, this will cause nil panic
    fmt.Print("s=", s, "\nsb=")
    for _, c := range sb {
        fmt.Printf("%c", c)
    }
    fmt.Println()

}
```

Output:

```
=== RUN   TestString
&b=0xc000218000
&s=0xc00021a000
&sb=0xc000218020
b.data=824635867152
s.data=824635867152
sb.data=824635867152
s=XYc1234
sb=XYc1234
```

These variables all share the same memory.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, no reflect, and I think it is portable. **s** is your string and **b** is your bytes slice

```
var b []byte
bb:=(*[3]uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))[:]
copy(bb, (*[2]uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))[:])
bb[2] = bb[1]
// use b
```

Remember, bytes value should not be modified (will panic). re-slicing is ok (for example: `bytes.split(b, []byte{','}` )